# A basic animation question

Tags: android, graphics

I want to have a cartoonish stork fly across my screen (slowly flapping his wings) and land on a post.  I have an artist that can draw it for me and said it could be a gif file.  I'm guessing that means it would be like a cartoon movie.  Is this easy to put in my app or do I need to do something entirely different?  My only experience with any graphics in android is displaying a picture using ImageView.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not deal with animated GIFs well. You apparently can play one back using `VideoView`, but I have not tried that. You can also set up an [`AnimationDrawable` resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame) (an XML container for the frames of your animation).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want:

http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-ideal-imageviewer-EzCz.aspx